# How to calculate normals or surfaces in 3D using angles?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, 3d, angle

For example in 2D space:

[image]

It is possible to calculate unit normal, $\vec{n}$, using $\theta$ and a bit of the unit-circle application: $$\vec{n} = (\sin{\theta}, -\cos{\theta})$$

I want to know is the same rules apply for 3D:

[image]

If it looks confusing:

- Plane **a** has no elevation
- Plane **b** is elevated on plane **a** by $\theta$
- $\phi$ is the angle made between the x-axis and Plane **a**

Think about the 2D cartesian graph turning into the 3D cartesian graph above, but now the entire slope is shifted by angle of $\phi$ in the horizontal direction (from the x-axis).

Now, to calculate $\vec{n}$ in 3D graph, do the same rules apply as the 2D graph (ie, $$\vec{n} = (\sin{\theta}, -\cos{\theta}, z)$$, and if so, how would we calculate z? Basically, I want to calculate the normal of plane **b** using its angle of inclination. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Continuing on @user 's answer:

[image]

I know $\angle X$ (Angle made with the y-axis / its rotation around the x-axis)

I know $\angle Y$ (Angle made with the x-axis / its rotation around the y-axis)

I know $\angle Z = \theta$ (Angle made with the x-axis / its rotation around the z-axis)

**Is it now possible to calculate $\phi$?** ... so that I can calculate the normal.

Comment: Spherical coordinates will help

Comment: @Vedant Chourey Thanks for the suggestion, but I do not quite understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a normal vector in the space $N=(A,B,C)$ the first step is to make this vector unitary by

$$n=\frac{N}{|N|}=\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}},\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}},\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}\right)=(a,b,c)$$

then by [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions), beeing $r=|n|=1$, we have

- $a=\cos \theta \sin \phi$
- $b=\sin \theta \sin \phi$
- $c=\cos \phi$

with

- $\phi = \arccos c$
- $\theta = \arctan \frac a b$ (adjusting properly for the qudrant and in case $b=0$; see also [atan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2))

[image]
(credit Wikipedia)

---

**Edit**

What you have are the angles for [direction cosines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine), therefore with your symbols

- $a= \cos y$
- $b=\cos x$

Comment: I understand how the angles and sides work, but I cannot understand how you have used it to achieve the unit normal of the line.

Comment: I’ve assumed we already have a normal vector. Are you interested on how we can obtain a normal?

Comment: Yes, please, thank you!

Comment: @SnipingPoodle We can consider the normal in space only for surfaces but I see you are referring to a line. Could you please better clarify this point? What is the line or surface for which you need to obtain the/a normal?

Comment: Its actually a surface; I cannot calculate the plane/surface's normal using the equation $(ax + by +cz +d = 0)$, which is why i am trying to calculate its normal using its angle of inclination.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle If you have the plane equation (or the tangent plane equation) $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ the/a normal vector is indeed $N=(A,B,C)$ and then you can proceed as indicated to obtian the normal by angles.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not quite understand. What if I do not have the equation $+++=0$ and I only have the angles? Is it still possible to calculate the normal vector only using the angles of the plane?

Comment: @SnipingPoodle If you have the angles you can use the expression given to calculate $a$, $b$ and $c$. From the scheme is not clear at all which angles you have at your disposal.

Comment: I need to calculate $\phi$. I have edited this in my answer to be clearer. If I can calculate $\phi$ then I can use your method to calculate the normal.

Comment: Ah ok now it is clear, I add something on that.

Comment: Thank you, this finally solved my problem!

Comment: Well done! You are welcome! Bye